# Behat Mink webdriver session is destroyed after every feature in a suite

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, behat, mink

I am trying to automate sugarcrm functionality with behat BDD and Mink with selenium webdriver for php. I have properly installed both of them and able to run behat and mink together. for example checking login on sugarcrm as one feature.

Now the problem is when i create two feature file say login.feature and setup.feature. Behat successfully automate login process in browser but as soon as it switches to setup.feature which require login session to be maintained from previous feature, it destroy session and comes back to login window. therefore, second feature test is always failing.

How i can maintain session for every feature in my feature suite?

Just to tell you guys that i have also tried them in a single feature file as different scenario but with no luck as the same thing is haapening

Please Help me if anyone knows about it.

Comment: Are you opening new browser session for second test case ?

Comment: no i am not. The browser stays open from the first feature. but always logout automatically before second feature start. which simply means that session is getting destroyed after every feature execution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Features and scenarios should be **independent**. It is THE expected behaviour that if you do something in one scenario, the state is not carried to the next one.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but you definitely doing something wrong.

Edit:

If you need to log user in before every scenario simply write a meta step which will perform all the necessary operations:

```
Given I am logged in
```

You could use [step execution chaining](http://docs.behat.org/guides/2.definitions.html#step-execution-chaining) or simply call Mink directly.

If every scenario in your feature file requires logging in you can use background:

```
Background:
    Given I am logged in

Scenario: Listing users
    Given ...

Scenario: Removing a user
    Given ...
```

Comment: all i am trying to do is to avoid login to application before every scenario or feature. It just dont look nice to rewrite the same code again and again. Don't you think so?

Comment: I think you're misusing behat. If your scenario requires logging in, it should be explicitly defined as a step. You have multiple ways of avoiding duplication. Read more on Gherkin syntax (http://docs.behat.org/guides/1.gherkin.html) and Behat itself. I have a feeling, however, that you're trying to write functional tests with Behat. In such case you'd be better of with Mink alone.

Comment: Yes i am trying to write functional tests with behat like most of the people do with cucumber and watir-webdriver [read this very good article](http://www.cheezyworld.com/2010/12/16/ui-tests-putting-it-all-together/) and i think its a wonderful way to check different scenarios in BDD framework.

Comment: I didn't express myself clearly. Nothing wrong with functional tests, I only think that in many cases Mink is sufficient and Behat gives an overhead. I'm not sure if this is your case, I'm only sure you misunderstood how Behat (or cucumber) work (since you  expect state to be shared between scenarios). I updated my answer to give you more hints.

Comment: I implmented Background yesterday only and in a way it is stil a duplication of code btw feature suite n yes i know behat gives an overhead but in my case most of the functionality scenarios comes from people who do not want to indulge in php programming. Therefore, all i was trying to give them as much abstraction from programming as i can. It seems for now i have to settle for repeating code in every feature file. May be some day if i have sometime i will try to look deeper into behat framework for customize myself bt thanx anyways for your suggestions and giving so much time to my question

Comment: sorry i coudnot vote your answer as it requires 15 reputation pt. :)

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Jakub Zalas answer

Still if your goal is to get rid of duplicate code declaring background in every feature i believe you can use [hooks](http://docs.behat.org/guides/3.hooks.html) to perform all required actions before each scenario