# How to Login only one time and then run a lot of scenarios

Tags: web, behat, mink

I'm a newbie in BDD and i would like to know how can i do some step before the beginning of my scenarios but only one time.

Concretely, i would like to login in my website and do some scenarios.

Currently, i have a background which log my user and after i have some scenarios.
The problem is that for all of them, my background is repeated.

How can i do to avoid that ?

Thank you in advance.

```html
Feature:
    User's module verification.
    As a user, i have to be able to manage my profil.
    
    # Background do an user's connection and go to his profile.
    Background:
        Given I am logged in


# -------------------SUMMARY MANAGEMENT---------------------
    @javascript @success @raz @summary
    Scenario: Deletion of the summary.
        When I click on the element at xpath "//*[@id='presentation']"
        And I write in the element at xpath "//*[@id='profile-content-presentation']/div/div/div[2]/div/span/div/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/textarea" value ""
        And I click on the element at xpath "//*[@id='profile-content-presentation']/div/div/div[2]/div/span/div/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]"
        And I wait for 1 seconds
        Then I should see "Aucun résumé pour l'instant"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [behat hooks](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/3.hooks.html) to automatically log user in before every scenario.

You could also combine this with tags to avoid logging user in, in scenarios taged in a certain way (or do the opposite, depending on how many of each you have).

Also see [Behat Mink webdriver session is destroyed after every feature in a suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614524/behat-mink-webdriver-session-is-destroyed-after-every-feature-in-a-suite/12619324#12619324)